Why my second dropdown of multi level dropdown does not load data
I'm a little new to flutter. I have two DropdownButtons. The second depends on the selection of the first.
The data of the first I retrieve from the database. It poses no problem.  Mais le second n'affiche aucune donnée bien que la liste de ses données ne soit pas vide.
First DropdownButton
Province?  maProvince;
Ville? ville;
List<Ville> villes = [];
FutureBuilder<List<Province>>(
    future: dbHelper.allProvinces(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
         return Text("Erreur du chargement des provinces.");
    }else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty){
         return Text("Aucune province trouvée.");
    }else{
         List<Province> provinces = snapshot.data!;
         return DropdownButtonFormField<Province>(
                  value: maProvince,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                     labelText: "Choisir une province",
                     border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  items: provinces.map((province){
                    return DropdownMenuItem<Province>(
                       value: province,
                       child: Text((province.nomProvince))
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (province) async{
                      final choises = await dbHelper.citiesOfAProvince(province!.id);
                      setState(() {
                         maProvince = province!;
                         villes = choises;
                         ville = choises[0];
                      });
                  },
                             
                );
           }
        }
    )

The variable villes,I use to load data of my second dropdownButton contains the data when I select an element from the first, but But no items are displayed.
Second DropdownButton
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
   child: ButtonTheme(
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<Ville>(
               value: ville,
               onChanged: (Ville? newValue) async{
                    setState((){
                    ville = newValue!;});
               },
               
               items: villes.map((ville){
                   return DropdownMenuItem<Ville>(
                        child: Text(ville.nom_ville),
                        value: ville
                    );
              }).toList(),
         )
     )
 )

What am I not doing well?
Help please !

Please check if show any nullable error in your log view.

there is no nullable error. but the second dropdown is grayed out. I cannot perform an action

you have to load second dropdown data when you set first data from 1st dropdown. for that initially second dropdown will be hided.
If you use futurebuilder for 2nd dropdown it will be fixed.

@SamuChakraborty how can i do that please ?
